# Change in Metaclass handling between python 3.4 and 3.5

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have the following structure (for overriding Django model behaviour):

```
class CustomModelBase(models.base.ModelBase):
    ...

class CustomModel(six.with_metaclass(CustomModelBase), models.base.Model):
    ...
```

where in `django.db.models.base`, Model is defined as:

```
class Model(six.with_metaclass(ModelBase)):
    ...
```

So, I have a class `CustomModel` derived from `Model`. The metaclass of `Model` is `ModelBase`. The derived class has a metaclass of `CustomModelBase`, which is derived from `ModelBase`.

Under python 3.4.5, this was fine. Running this under python 3.5.3, and I get:

```
    class CustomModel(six.with_metaclass(CustomModelBase), models.Model):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Which it is...so I'm not sure exactly why it's complaining, and going through the change list from python 3.4 to 3.5 mentions nothing I can see that would change this behaviour (Django version is 1.10.4 and hasn't changed).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the problem was in `six`, as changing the declaration to:

```
class CustomModel(models.Model, metaclass=CustomModelBase):
```

made the problem go away. Still don't know the root cause, but hopefully that helps someone.